# Can't load resource from jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I met problem when trying to export my java project into runnable jar. the code runs in eclipse, but can't get resource after exported. My dir structure in eclipse

```
project_A - src - package_a - a.java
                            - res - b.png
```

structure in jar

```
A - src - A.class
    res - b.png
    META-INF - MANIFEST
```

what's in the MANIFEST

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Class-Path: .  
Main-Class: project_A.A_class
```

I'm using following code to get image resource

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("res/b.png");          
img_bg = ImageIO.read(url);
```

This code works in Eclipse, but only with relative path, and if I set `res dir` as the same level with `src  dir`, above code doesn't work either, always return input is null.

I can't see what path this program get when I execute jar, don't know how to debug without output information.

So can anyone help me figure out what is the right structure and how to get image in jar?

---

my mistake, the first eclipse structure is wrong, it's the same structure as shown in Betlista's anwser

Comment: Try using `getClass().getResource("/res/b.png")`.  Also, are you sure that `b.png` actually resides within the Jar file, as I though Eclipse didn't included resources from the `src` directory...

Comment: Your code is invalid Java code. Your main class entry in the manifest doesn't match any of your classes. The name of the class files in the jar don't match the names of the Java source files. Tell us the truth.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have several wrong statement in your question, my project looks like:

[image]

and this is content of `ResourceTest`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class ResourceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL resource = ResourceTest.class.getResource("/pict.png");
        assert resource != null : "Resource is null";
        ImageIO.read(resource);
    }

}
```

I exported `res_test.jar` and when I run `java -jar res_test.jar` it works for me.

content of the jar is

```
res_test.jar
+- META-INF
   +- MANIFEST.MF
+- pict.png
+- ResourceTest.class
```

and content of MANIFEST.MF is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: ResourceTest
```